# Win10 universal app GridView cannot scroll

Tags: c#, gridview

I pretty much used the sample on [this site](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh780644.aspx) to create a Gridview. Somehow, on windows 10 universal app, the gridview isn't scrollable when the content exceeds the screen. Clearly remember that the code works fine in windows 8. I believe that I am missing something somewhere. Copied from the site:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ImageOverlayGalleryFolderDataTemplate">
        <Grid Background="#FF939598" Height="200" Width="300">
            <Image Source="{Binding Image}"  Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Background="#CC000000" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" 
                   Margin="10,3,0,0" Width="186" Height="20" 
                   TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Foreground="White"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource AppBarItemForegroundThemeBrush}">
    <GridView x:Name="ImageOverlayGalleryFolderGrid" 
      CanReorderItems="True" CanDragItems="True" 
      ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ImageOverlayGalleryFolderDataTemplate}" >
        <GridView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <ItemsWrapGrid MaximumRowsOrColumns="5"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemsPanel>
    </GridView>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add following properties: 
`ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Disabled" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Auto"`

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by putting the GridView into a ScrollViewer.